# Customizing dockable windows in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

When developing on a system with dual monitors, I like to make the most of the extra space by stretching Visual Studio across both.  It is fantastic to be able to see the Output, Breakpoints, Error List, Object Browser, and ReSharper windows at the same time without having to make them tiny and dock them in the main window, which leaves less space for code.

I place the main VS window on one monitor with the tabbed document and Solution Explorer windows.  Any other windows I want to display are placed on the second monitor and docked together.  The only problem I encounter with this method is that the main tabbed document window with the VS menu bar is the only window that can be maximized.  The additional windows such as Solution Explorer, Breakpoints and Error List can only be stretched, docked or closed.  I often go through the tedious work of selecting and laying out secondary windows only to have that layout be erased when I close VS.

Does anyone know of a VS add-in that gives you a window that (1) is maximizable, and (2) other windows can be docked in (ReSharper only does 2) ?  Barring that, does anyone know of a good resource to learn how to develop VS add-ins?  I am keen to do so myself if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of either of your suggestions, although I would also love to see better multiple-monitor support in VS. What I have done, though, is saved various window layouts (Tools > Import and Export Settings, and check only Window Layout) so that I can switch easily when I feel like it.

Comment: In versions of VS through 2008, Import and Export Settings is the best way I found to do this.  Scott Guthrie recently announced that VS 2010 will have much stronger native support for multiple monitors.  

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/31/multi-monitor-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx